# Converting a cell to matrix

Tags: matrix, matlab

I have an array of cells I want it to be converted into matrix of 2D

I did the following:

```
B = [9 8 8 8 10 10 10 10 9 9];
A = [8,9,10]; 
Y = arrayfun(@(x) find(B==x),unique(A),'Un',0);
```

The result is:

```
Y = {[2,3,4] , [1,10,9] , [5,6,7,8] }
```

Now I want Y to be like this:

```
 Y = 2  3  4  0  0 0 0 0 0 0 
     1  10 9  0  0 0 0 0 0 0 
     5  6  7  8  0 0 0 0 0 0
```

a 2D matrix with rows of size A and columns of size B , How can I do that in MATLAB?

Comment: I assumed `[1,10,9]` is a typo -> it returns `[1,9,10]`, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change your last line to:

```
Y = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x) [find(B==x) 0*find(B~=x)],unique(A),'Uni',0).')
```

to also include all values which do not pass the condition and set them to zero. Then all cells have the same size and you can use `cell2mat`.

```
Y =

     2     3     4     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     9    10     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     5     6     7     8     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be faster, as it avoids `cellfun`:

```
Y = bsxfun(@eq, unique(A).', B); %'// compare elements from A and B
Y = bsxfun(@times, Y, 1:size(Y,2)); %// transform each 1 into its row index
[~, ind] = sort(~Y, 2); %// this will move zeros to the right
ind = bsxfun(@plus, (ind-1)*size(Y,1), (1:size(Y,1)).'); %'// make linear index
Y = Y(ind);
```